# Spring Cloud Kubernetes: Support for fail policy on the event that ConfigMap can’t be read

Tags: spring-cloud-kubernetes

Due to business requirements, we require the use of a Kubernetes client for an app running on Spring Boot 2.4. Whilst testing the ConfigMap loader (specified via a bootstrap file), we noticed that, in the event that the ConfigMap cannot be loaded, the app simply ignores this issue and continues the start-up process. For our requirements, our app must at least fail to start-up if it cannot load the ConfigMap.

At first glance, we didn’t see anything in the documentation suggesting a possible workaround to this… Then, going through older issues, we see that something similar to this has already been asked for (i.e. [#411](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/441) ) but in the context of a retry policy.

We would like to know if there is, by any chance, a fail policy feature already being worked on?

If not, is there an already existing workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a PR [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/pull/873) that will support this, via the `fail-fast` property. There are no estimates when it will be released, though; subscribe to the issue and get notified.